# Simple Haskell program causes 'Illegal signature in pattern' error

Tags: haskell

I've decided to teach myself Haskell and I have never been so frustrated in all my life. I am going through the tutorial at http://lisperati.com/haskell/ which is the easiest one I could find.  All that I am trying to do is read a text file called [people.txt](http://lisperati.com/haskell/people.txt) which contains a list of numbers and print the length of the list. This code is straight from the tutorial.

```
import Data.List

type Person = [Int]

main = do

    people_text <- readFile "people.txt"
    let people :: [Person]
            people = read people_text

    putStr "Number of people "
    putStr (length people_text)
```

When I try to run the file with **runHaskell tutorial03.hs** I get this error message

```
tutorial03.hs:9:13:
Illegal signature in pattern: [Person] people
    Use -XScopedTypeVariables to permit it
```

Using the XScopedTypeVariables flag I get

```
tutorial03.hs:10:17: Not in scope: type variable `people'
```

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It's your indentation.  Make sure the type signature and the definition of `people` are at the same level of indentation.

Comment: @luqui - Thanks .. now it gives me a 'parse error on input = '

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Luqui's right that indentation is the issue. The compiler is treating your definition as if it were

```
let people :: [Person] people = read people_text
```

which does indeed look like you're writing a type signature in a pattern (and using `people` both as the function name and a pattern variable, to boot -- peculiar but permitted!).

Crucially, `let` is a *layout* keyword, introducing a block of lines which should all be indented to the same horizontal position. By following the signature with a more-indented line, you indicate that you're contuing the line with the signature, rather than starting a new line for the actual definition. If you don't like this fussy layout convention, you can use noisy semicolons.

If you want your definition to be treated as two lines, you either need to be careful to line up the `people`s vertically...

```
let people :: [Person]
    people = read people_text
```

or to signal the line ending explicitly with a semicolon.

```
let people :: [Person] ;
        people = read people_text
```

The former would be preferable, although I expect most Haskellers would just supply a type annotation for `read people_text` rather than a signature for the definition, like this:

```
let people = read people_text :: [Person]
```

Once you've fixed that, you'll need to contend with the fact that the length of the list is a number, but putStr outputs strings. The `print` command may be more useful for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks! that did it. Wish I could give +2 for picking up on my next error as well :)

Answer (score 1):

change it to this, works for me:

```
...
    let people :: [Person]
        people = read people_text

...
    print (length people_text)
```

Comment: I don't get it. What was the change?

Comment: Nevermind - pigworker explained the vertical line up, now I see it.